# How to upgrade ubuntu from 14.04 to 18.04?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 18.04

The last week of next month ubuntu will most likely release 18.04 LTS. Now my system is 14.04 and next month I want to upgrade it to 18.04. Can I directly upgrade my system from 14.04 to 18.04 or I have to first upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 and then to 18.04? I really want to avoid the second method of upgrading.

Edit:

How should I update 14.04 to 16.04. I tried this method `sudo update-manager -d` and installed all the necessary software and restarted the system. Again I run `sudo update-manager -d` and it showed that my computer is upto date but doesnt have any button to update to 16.04

Comment: You can try, but that way is unsupported, and lots of things changed.

Comment: `but that way is unsupported`  can you explain of which you are talking about

Comment: Your edit is really a different question. Please see [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477/301745)

Comment: The 2 questions reported above speak about old versions (2010,12->14,11->13...) and report really _old news_. The official page about [release notes if LTS 18.04 Bionic Beaver](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes) at present say nothing about the _"version skipping"_.  Is there any official (2018 updated)  answer about a direct upgrade from 14.04 to 18.04?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No.

Ubuntu does have LTS→LTS upgrades, allowing you to skip intermediate non-LTS releases...
But you *can't* skip intermediate LTS releases. **You *have* to go via 16.04.**

Unless you want to do a fresh install of 18.04 on release.

I should also note that the LTS upgrade pathways are usually only available  *some time* after the main release. So don't expect to be able to upgrade from 16.04 on the day of 18.04's release.

Comment: So I should upgrade it first to 16.04 can you also include the code for that.

Comment: Can you please check my edited question

Comment: @Oli. Hi, you said _"But you can't skip intermediate LTS releases"_. Is it a strict policy, is it only the past experience or did you read about it on some official ubuntu documentation?

Comment: Here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes , it says that upgrade will be available at **end of july**.