# Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 16.10, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 18.04 and getting this error everytime:

`An upgrade from 'yakkety' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool.`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015728/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-14-04-to-18-04?rq=1

Comment: I tried everything mentioned in these answers but nothing worked. I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu from the ISO file. Nothing else is working for me. Or should I wait for some more time?

Comment: Your plan to install Ubuntu from the Ubuntu 18.04 ISO file is the best way for you to install Ubuntu 18.04. You need to make a bootable Ubuntu 18.04 USB stick: [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb/451866?s=6|5.7008#451866) You don't need to wait. You can start immediately.

Comment: The planned upgrade path from 16.10 (2016.October release) was to 17.04 (2017.April release), then to 17.10 (2017.October) then to 18.04 LTS (2018.April).  Each of those planned/intended steps are now EOL & thus the tools don't support it unless you modifying them.  If you need a longer life use LTS or long-term-support releases that have lives of 5 years and not just 9 months. I'd recommend backup your data, then install of 18.04

Comment: When installing 18.04, you can install with 'something else' & tell it not to format partitions, so hopefully most everything will survive, but backup anyway first. This will delete & then re-create most system folders, so software will be deleted, then re-installed if all goes well (if the programs exist in the 18.04 repos)

Comment: look for Upgrade from 16.04  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version/).
Before you will upgrade to the 17.10 and the to 18.04.

When you login you will have both unity and gnome available but if I remember exactly you can' t use unity.
With the first upgrade some things (for example files) in the launcher bar will disappear and also some options in the  top panel.

If you search here you will find how restore the top panel options (and add programs to the launcher bar is easy).

But don't do it because after the second upgrade you will lost them again. Some apps (for example Open Arena) don't work with 17.10 and 18.04.

I prefer unity instead of gnome and you can install it using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`.

I suggest to install it using the iso, using the same username and password without formatting the home partition you won' t lose that partition. Made some researches to be sure to not lost something important for you.

After the terminal update i reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04.