# Repository does have released file error while updateting apt

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I am constantly getting the code above, some repositories does not have released file. Full log of `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                     
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                      
Hit:4 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease                                   
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                     
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports InRelease
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security universe main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates universe main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports universe main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Should I delete some sources from the file above? Which?

EDIT:
`cat /etc/os-release`:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.04 (Disco Dingo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.04"
VERSION_ID="19.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=disco
UBUNTU_CODENAME=disco
```

`grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include "*.list"`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu disco main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu disco main
```

Comment: None of those sources are valid anymore. Some have been defunct for many years. Back up your data and clean-install a supported release of Ubuntu. Mark your calendar so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: You are using an end-of-life version (14.04, Ubuntu Trusty), and need to upgrade to a supported release. This might answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015728/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-14-04-to-18-04

Comment: @Herdsman What it your Ubuntu version? Please add output of `cat /etc/os-release`. Also show the full sources.list by `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` . If output is long, use pastebin.

Comment: @N0rbert editted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was already mentioned both 14.04 LTS (trusty) and 19.04 (disco) are EOL.

So if you want to save currently running system you need to fix sources.list first to the *disco* version and then upgrade it to currently supported release - 19.10 (eoan).

At first we need to fix the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to normal repository lines. You have to open it with any text editor like `pkexec gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and fill it with following contents:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
```

Also do not forget to comment lines with *lucid* and *trusty* and save the file.
Then update package lists and install all upgrades with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then upgrade this system to 19.10 by running `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: wait, till system bakcup `sudo tar czf /backup.tar.gz --exclude=/bin --exclude=lib --exclude=libx32 --exclude=mnt --exclude=root --exclude=snap --exclude=sys --exclude=boot --exclude=dev --exclude=lost+found --exclude=run --exclude=srv --exclude=tmp --exclude=cdrom --exclude=proc --exclude=shepherd/.cache --exclude=shepherd/.cpan --exclude=shepherd/.cpanm --exclude=shepherd/.mozilla--exclude=shepherd/.perl5 --exclude=opt / &`